# Python "cannot find the file specified" but os.path.exists() is True

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, popen

I am running Python 3.7.16 inside a Windows 11 Virtual Machine. Suppose I want to get info on a file (stored at `C:\Users\Foo\Documents\bar\doc.txt`) using a CMD `dir` call via subprocess.Popen (there are better ways of doing this task, but it demonstrates the problem).

A call to os.path.exists() says that the file exists (which is correct!), but when I try to examine it with subprocess.Popen, Windows says that it cannot find it.

```
import subprocess
import os
path = os.path.join("C:", os.sep, "Users", "Foo", "Documents", "bar", "doc.txt")
# path = 'C:\\Users\\Foo\\Documents\\bar\\doc.txt'
os.path.exists(path) # -> True
subprocess.Popen([fr"dir {path}"]) # -> "The system cannot find the file specified"
subprocess.Popen([fr"dir {path}"], shell = True) # -> "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."
```

Any idea what might be going wrong here?

Comment: You have to give the parts of the command as separate strings in the list.

Comment: `subprocess.Popen(f"dir {path}", shell=True)` (`dir` is a shell builtin, so `shell=True` is required)

Comment: Ok, it was as simple as this :( Thank you! I'm confused because my example was just a representative version of a script that seems to pass a command `cmd` to Popen as one long string, but replacing this with `cmd.split()` solves the problem in my actual code. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're encountering is related to how the subprocess.Popen function handles arguments and the shell parameter. When using the shell parameter, the command should be passed as a single string, not as a list of separate arguments.

Here's how you can modify your code to make it work:

```
import subprocess
import os

path = os.path.join("C:", os.sep, "Users", "Foo", "Documents", "bar", "doc.txt")

# Using shell=True and passing the command as a single string
subprocess.Popen(fr'dir "{path}"', shell=True)
```

In this example, we use shell=True and pass the command as a single string. Additionally, we've added double quotes around the path to handle any spaces in the file path.

Remember that using shell=True can have security implications, as it can expose your code to potential shell injection vulnerabilities. Whenever possible, it's recommended to avoid using shell=True and use the list form of the Popen call, passing the individual arguments.

If you prefer to use the list form and avoid shell=True, you can use the following approach:

```
import subprocess
import os

path = os.path.join("C:", os.sep, "Users", "Foo", "Documents", "bar", "doc.txt")

# Using the list form and avoiding shell=True
subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/c", "dir", path])
```

In this version, we explicitly call the "cmd" command with the "/c" flag to execute the dir command. This approach avoids the need for shell=True and keeps your code more secure.